# Webpack bundle throwing content length mismatch error

Tags: reactjs, go, webpack

I'm working on a React project that gets served by a Go application.

I've been trying to integrate a component library, first with Ant Design, and now with Material UI.

In both instances, as soon as I add a simple component (in this case a Button), my webpack bundle throws `net::ERR_CONTENT_LENGTH_MISMATCH` in Chrome.

Before adding a component library, my outputted bundle is around 1mb, when adding Material it grows to about 5.5mb, with Ant it was about 11mb.

The strange behavior is that this only happens when I bundle the resources in the development mode configuration with Webpack. If I build for production, everything is fine, although I do get the warning about the bundle size exceeding the recommended limit.

My webpack looks like this:

```
const path = require("path");
const webpack = require("webpack");
const dotenv = require("dotenv-webpack");

const miniCSS = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");
const CopyPlugin = require("copy-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = {
  entry: path.resolve(__dirname, "src/index.tsx"),

  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
    filename: "js/anx.js",
  },

  // Enable sourcemaps for debugging webpack's output.
  devtool: "source-map",

  resolve: {
    // Add '.ts' and '.tsx' as resolvable extensions.
    extensions: [".ts", ".tsx", ".js"],

    alias: {
      components: path.resolve(__dirname, "src/components"),
      containers: path.resolve(__dirname, "src/containers"),
      src: path.resolve(__dirname, "src"),
    },
  },

  plugins: [
    new miniCSS({
      filename: "css/anx.css",
    }),
  ],

  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.ts(x?)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: "ts-loader",
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: miniCSS.loader,
            options: {
              publicPath: "/dist/css",
            },
          },
          "css-loader",
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.s[ac]ss$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: miniCSS.loader,
            options: {
              publicPath: "/dist/css",
            },
          },
          "css-loader",
          "sass-loader",
        ],
      },
      // All output '.js' files will have any sourcemaps re-processed by 'source-map-loader'.
      {
        enforce: "pre",
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: "source-map-loader",
      },
    ],
  },

  // When importing a module whose path matches one of the following, just
  // assume a corresponding global variable exists and use that instead.
  // This is important because it allows us to avoid bundling all of our
  // dependencies, which allows browsers to cache those libraries between builds.
  externals: {
    react: "React",
    "react-dom": "ReactDOM",
  },
};

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
  module.exports.devtool = "source-map";
  module.exports.mode = "production";
  module.exports.optimization = { minimize: true };
  module.exports.plugins = (module.exports.plugins || []).concat([
    new CopyPlugin([
      {
        from: "node_modules/react/umd/react.production.min.js",
        to: "js/react.js",
      },
      {
        from: "node_modules/react-dom/umd/react-dom.production.min.js",
        to: "js/react-dom.js",
      },
    ]),
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      "process.env": {
        NODE_ENV: '"production"',
      },
    }),
    new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
      minimize: true,
    }),
  ]);
} else {
  module.exports.devtool = "eval-source-map";
  module.exports.mode = "development";
  module.exports.plugins = (module.exports.plugins || []).concat([
    new CopyPlugin([
      {
        from: "node_modules/react/umd/react.development.js",
        to: "js/react.js",
      },
      {
        from: "node_modules/react-dom/umd/react-dom.development.js",
        to: "js/react-dom.js",
      },
    ]),
    new dotenv({ path: "secrets/.env.dev" }),
  ]);
}
```

I suspect that, in development mode, Webpack includes the source maps and the bundle balloons in size, and this somehow results in the content mismatch error. However, I'm not totally sure. Any help would be appreciated

edit: I found a working solution for this by replacing `eval-source-map` with `source-map` in the development environments devtool. I'm not totally sure why this works; my suspicion is that it has something to do with my project running on WSL and the bundle sizes that are produced.

Comment: Do you have a reproducible repo?